# Puppeteer old Headless deprecation warning

Tags: puppeteer

i cant run wppconnect server i got this error :

info:     Checking for updates
info:     You're up to date
info:     [session:browser] Using browser folder '/home/abdo/projects/wppconnectFromMohammed/wppconnect/tokens/session'
info:     [session:browser] Initializing browser...

Puppeteer old Headless deprecation warning:
In the near future `headless: true` will default to the new Headless mode
for Chrome instead of the old Headless implementation. For more
information, please see https://developer.chrome.com/articles/new-headless/.
Consider opting in early by passing `headless: "new"` to `puppeteer.launch()`
If you encounter any bugs, please report them to https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/new/choose.

error:    [session:browser] Error no open browser
error:    [session:browser] Timed out after waiting 30000ms
TimeoutError: Timed out after waiting 30000ms
at /home/abdo/projects/wppconnectFromMohammed/wppconnect/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/util.js:287:19
at /home/abdo/projects/wppconnectFromMohammed/wppconnect/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/third_party/rxjs/rxjs.js:3:59978
at t.f._next (/home/abdo/projects/wppconnectFromMohammed/wppconnect/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/third_party/rxjs/rxjs.js:3:11821)
at t.next (/home/abdo/projects/wppconnectFromMohammed/wppconnect/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/third_party/rxjs/rxjs.js:3:6459)
at t. (/home/abdo/projects/wppconnectFromMohammed/wppconnect/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/third_party/rxjs/rxjs.js:3:71381)
at t._execute (/home/abdo/projects/wppconnectFromMohammed/wppconnect/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/third_party/rxjs/rxjs.js:3:28234)
at t.execute (/home/abdo/projects/wppconnectFromMohammed/wppconnect/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/third_party/rxjs/rxjs.js:3:28057)
at t.flush (/home/abdo/projects/wppconnectFromMohammed/wppconnect/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/third_party/rxjs/rxjs.js:3:32540)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)

i usally use this command " node server.js " and it works but today it wont???

Comment: The headless deprecation warning is just a warning, not an error. Your real problem seems to be `Error no open browser` or `Timed out after waiting 30000ms`, but can you share a [mcve] of the code, package.json and environment so we can reproduce and help? Thanks.

Comment: "command [...] works but today it wont???" -- what changed? If you're using git, did you try to diff against your previous code?